# Docklayoutmanager documentgroup

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

Is it possible to drag `DocumentPanels` between different `DockLayoutManagers` in different windows?
I am using version 13.5.7 and MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that currently this option is not yet available.

Here what I have found via the [DevExpress Search](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/):

**[Provide the capability to dock panels to the DockManager in another window](https://www.devexpress.com/issue=S170377)**

You'd better to contact the vendor's support directly.

Comment: i know its not availbe but was wondering if its possible to implement

Comment: Once your question has been answered, accept a corresponding Answer :)